# Jquery: control multiple news ticker

Tags: jquery, news-ticker

I am working with *jQuery* news ticker [plugin](http://buildinternet.com/project/totem/). And it worked fine, but when I put multiple news ticker in my page, news ticker `control(start,stop,next/pre)` not work. when i click in control 1, this control worked with all news ticker box, But in need to worked `control` for each box. `i.e: control1 for box1, control2 for box2`. how to fix this? [ONLINE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BBKING/ucvdB/) (in action please click in first `controlbar`.)

HTML:

```
<ul id="vertical-ticker">
            <li>One Time</li>
            <li>Baby</li>
            <li>One Less Lonely Girl</li>
            <li>Somebody to Love</li>
            <li>Eenie Meenie</li>
            <li>Never Say Never</li>
            <li>U Smile</li>
</ul>
<p><a href="#" id="ticker-previous">Previous</a> / <a href="#" id="ticker-next">Next</a> / <a id="stop" href="#">Stop</a> / <a id="start" href="#">Start</a></p>
<ul id="vertical-ticker1">
            <li>One Time</li>
            <li>Baby</li>
            <li>One Less Lonely Girl</li>
            <li>Somebody to Love</li>
            <li>Eenie Meenie</li>
            <li>Never Say Never</li>
            <li>U Smile</li>
</ul>
    <p><a href="#" id="ticker-previous">Previous</a> / <a href="#" id="ticker-next">Next</a> / <a id="stop" href="#">Stop</a> / <a id="start" href="#">Start</a></p>
```

JQUERY:

```
$(function(){
            $('#vertical-ticker').totemticker({
                row_height  :   '100px',
                next        :   '#ticker-next',
                previous    :   '#ticker-previous',
                stop        :   '#stop',
                start       :   '#start',
                mousestop   :   true,
            });
        });
$(function(){
            $('#vertical-ticker1').totemticker({
                row_height  :   '100px',
                next        :   '#ticker-next',
                previous    :   '#ticker-previous',
                stop        :   '#stop',
                start       :   '#start',
                mousestop   :   true,
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplicate id's like `#ticker-next`, `#start`, `#stop`, etc. Those need to be unique both in the HTML and in the jQuery object map.

Answer (score 2):

Change the ids of the start buttons, there should be different ids for start button for each of the newsticker.

```
$(function(){
            $('#vertical-ticker').totemticker({
                row_height  :   '100px',
                next        :   '#ticker-next',
                previous    :   '#ticker-previous',
                stop        :   '#stop',
                start       :   '#start',
                mousestop   :   true,
            });
        });
$(function(){
            $('#vertical-ticker1').totemticker({
                row_height  :   '100px',
                next        :   '#ticker-next2',
                previous    :   '#ticker-previous2',
                stop        :   '#stop2',
                start       :   '#start2',
                mousestop   :   true,
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change `#vertical-ticker1` and `ticker-previous1` and `#ticker-next1` and `#start` and `#stop` too. 
**[jsfiddle Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/ucvdB/3/)**

**JavaScript**

```
$(function(){
        $('#vertical-ticker1').totemticker({
            row_height  :   '100px',
            next        :   '#ticker-next1',
            previous    :   '#ticker-previous1',
            stop        :   '#stop1',
            start       :   '#start1',
            mousestop   :   true,
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<p><a href="#" id="ticker-previous1">Previous</a> / <a href="#" id="ticker-next1">Next</a> / <a id="stop1" href="#">Stop</a> / <a id="start1" href="#">Start</a></p>
```